# Can't get gender and birthday with oauth API

Tags: oauth, deezer

I'm trying to get "gender" and "birthday" via Deezer api. I can see it is set in Profile but can't get it in response.

It is empty.

To reproduce.
1. Go to http://developers.deezer.com/api/explorer?url=user/me
2. Send request to http://api.deezer.com/user/me

Proof: 
[image]
[image]
[image]
Is it possible get those 2 values?

Answer (score 0):

These information are not actually available for legal reasons.